# Magento Export All Invoice In PDF

Tags: invoice, export

My accountant asked me an export of all my invoices at PDF (33972 invoice :/) . Is there a way to do it automatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can make a quick standalone script and run the following:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection');

$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='invoices.pdf'");

$pdf->render();
```

Although, with the number of invoices you have, I can't predict how long this is going to have run for (if it ever finishes) and how difficult this is going to be for your accountant!

Comment: it really depends on how much memory he has on his server :) I'm sure Magento will crash and won't be able to render 33972 PDFs at the same time, so I'd suggest to create some kind of queue & render invoices 1 by 1, or 100 by 100 (also depends on memory limit)

Comment: That's a good point @dsitovs. Rendering that many invoices in one go, will crash your PHP instance, or even your browser. Queuing them (and saving the PDFs locally) is the way to go