# Mass Print/Export invoices pdf separately

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

my tax consultant needs my invoices in separated .PDFs like invoicenumber.pdf - is this somehow possible? I only know the way to select them all in the backend and hit "Create Invoices" which prints one large .PDF file with all invoices - just need to get them separated and with the invoice-number as filename.

Has someone a solution for this please? I've played around with the solution posted in [Magento Export All Invoice In PDF](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67427/magento-export-all-invoice-in-pdf) but the result is always empty (even if I use $this instead of $invoices).

Thank you so much in advance, best greets, David

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/tree/feature/182 they already have implemented this :)